# How to annotate object as function argument?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to invoke this function

```
const logPerson = (person: { name: string; age: number }) => {
    console.log('name:', person.name, 'age:', person.age);
}
```

I tried

```
let person = (_name:'Mike Pompeo', _age:'25')
```

But

```
logPerson(person)
```

returns

```
[LOG]: "name:",  undefined,  "age:",  undefined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: *"I tried `let person = (_name:'Mike Pompeo', _age:'25')` but `logPerson(person)` returns `[LOG]: "name:",  undefined,  "age:",  undefined`."* All due respect, I find that hard to believe. `let person = (_name:'Mike Pompeo', _age:'25')` is a syntax error as of the first `:` (in JavaScript) or the `)` (in TypeScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`person` should be object. And also remove `_` for the key name.

```
let person = {name:'Mike Pompeo', age:'25'}
```